# How do I move a custom taxonomy meta box in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy, meta-boxes

Good day all :)

I'm using a custom post type (`publicite`) which also uses a custom taxonomy (`business_category`). Whenever I add a new post (`publicite`), I see that custom taxonomy metabox on the right side but I want it moved to the middle. So I started by removing the metabox with the following code:

```
remove_meta_box('business_categorydiv', 'publicite', 'side');
```

After reading online, it seems like I have to use the following line of code to add it again (or so I thought):

```
add_meta_box('business_categorydiv', __('Catégories'), 'post_categories_meta_box', 'publicite', 'normal', 'high');
```

The problem with it, is that it adds the default post category metabox (not the custom taxonomy one). I tried many things (like the one below) but none seem to work:

```
add_meta_box('business_categorydiv', __('Catégories'), 'post_business_category_meta_box', 'publicite', 'normal', 'high');
```

Any idea how this can be achieved?

Comment: Bingo! I had to supply an argument at the end like so: `add_meta_box('business_categorydiv', __('Catégories', 'wp-custom-posts'), 'post_categories_meta_box', 'publicite', 'normal', 'high', array('taxonomy' => 'business_category'));`

Comment: You should post your comment as an answer and accept it, to make sure future "passers by" will benefit from your solution :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bingo! I had to supply an argument at the end like so:

```
add_meta_box('business_categorydiv', __('Catégories', 'wp-custom-posts'), 'post_categories_meta_box', 'publicite', 'normal', 'high', array('taxonomy' => 'business_category'));
```